# for loop using activity diagram

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've written a pseudo code for an algorithm and I need to draw an activity diagram for it. But I'm having difficulty getting my head around how to display a for loop on an activity diagram. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Can we see this pseudo code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I represent a loop in an activity diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710695/how-do-i-represent-a-loop-in-an-activity-diagram)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/activity2.html) are some simple examples with code snipets on how to display **for loop** in activity diagram