# How to add the object type to the region iterative border in Enterprise Architect Activity Diagram?

Tags: for-loop, enterprise-architect, activity-diagram

I want to add the list elements to the borderline of a iterative region.

Like this image which is from another [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710695/how-to-present-a-loop-in-activity-diagram):

[image]

Comment: Manually or via API?

Comment: Manually, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the clicks:

- In the activity diagram choose to create a new Region

[image]

- Make it `iterative` (if you stick to the example)

[image]

- From the context choose `Structural Elements`

[image]

- And click `New`  to create an `Expansion Node`

[image]

Done!